# Laravel 4.x Alias a table using Eloquent while performing a join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm aware that in my Model I can alias my table like so:

```
protected $table = 'territories_sign_in_out AS tsio';
```

so that I can still use Eloquent to build collections but what about when I need to use the table in a join like this:

```
Territories::select('territories.id', 'tsio.signed_out')
           ->join('territories_sign_in_out', function($join) use ($id)
           {
               //
           })
           ->get();
```

Right now I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'as `tsio`.`publisher_id` = ? order 
by `territory_id` asc, `signed_in` asc' at line 1 (SQL: select * from 
`territories_sign_in_out` as `tsio` where `territories_sign_in_out` as 
`tsio`.`publisher_id` = 59 order by `territory_id` asc, `signed_in` asc)
```

Am I stuck just using Fluent?

```
DB::table('territories_sign_in_out AS tsio')...
```

I would like to also be able to build statements using `Eloquent` like this:

```
TerritoriesSignInOut::select('t.id', 't.label', 'tsio.signed_out', 'tsio.publisher_id')
                    ->join('territories AS t', 'tsio.territory_id', '=', 't.id')
                    ->whereNull('tsio.signed_in')
                    ->orderBy('t.label', 'ASC')
                    ->get();
```

and I can only do this by adding `as tsio` like I mentioned at the fore of this question.

To clarify table `territories` = model `Territories`. Table `territories_sign_in_out` = model `TerritoriesSignInOut`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alias it like:

```
Territories::select('territories.id', 'tsio.signed_out')
           ->join('territories_sign_in_out as tsio', function($join) use ($id) {
               //...
           })
           ->get();
```

To be more clear I'm re-writing the code again:

```
Territories::join('territories_sign_in_out as tsio', function($join) use ($id) {
               //...
           })
           ->select('territories.id', 'tsio.signed_out')
           ->get();
```

Comment: Sure - I understand that. But then how do I alias the table when I'm doing statements using the table `TerritoriesSignInOut (territories_sign_in_out)`? All the examples I've seen just seem to rely on Fluent meaning I have to choose one method or the other, not both.

Comment: In your `Territories` model, what is the table name and what is the other table name that you are joining ?

Comment: So what's wrong with your second approach, `TerritoriesSignInOut::join(...)` ?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the table name for `Territories` and what is the table name for `TerritoriesSignInOut` used in both models ?

Comment: That's what's throwing a mysql error. Seems like the pre-defined alias in my model is throwing it off. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `tsio`.`publisher_id` = ? `...

Comment: yes, it's aliasing it wrongly, you need to alias it in the join statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59976/discussion-between-jared-eitnier-and-werewolf-the-alpha).

Comment: I think probably there's just no way to do what I want since the alias in the `$table` variable is causing conflict.

Comment: Yes, you should avoid that.